# Understand Qemu Riscv NMI and Interrupts implementation

Tags: qemu, qemu-device, qemu-device-backend

I want to add NMI (Non-Maskable Interrupt) to Qemu Risc-v Virt machine. What's the best way to do it? Is it the same as a regular interrupt? How does Qemu emulate interrupts? I want to understand how Qemu emulates the HW behavior related to Interrupt implementation. Is there any good tutorial that explains this issue?

Comment: You will need to grasp understanding for both the architecture of RISC-V and the internal workings of QEMU. To implement an NMI, you'll need to modify the QEMU source code specific to RISC-V virt architecture.

Comment: I have an understanding of Risc-v and Qemu. I have a gap in how Qemu implements and triggers interrupts.

Comment: Someone can help me with this issue?